# My logic of performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, macos

This code here is js-ctypes. The code is crashing and I think it's to my misunderstanding of reading about doing stuff on the main thread from other threads.

My end goal is to set a window always on top from a secondary thread, so I have to run `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`

What I am doing is:

1. Create a class named `setWinAlwaysOnTop_class` with `objc_allocateClassPair`
2. Write my methods in javascript and convert to C (currently i wrote them to just log to console but after I get it working ill update to do `NSWindow` stuff)
3. Register unique selector name for my method with `sel_registerName`
4. Use `class_addMethod` to add my C methods from step 2 to class from step 1
5. `objc_registerClassPair` on the class from step 1
6. Allocation my class with `alloc`
7. Create instance of class with `init`
8. Do `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` on my instance of class created in step 7 with first argument being the unique selector name from step 3, setting 2nd arg `withObject` to `nil`, and final arg `waitUntilDone` to `YES`

Is this logic correct? And my crash is not due to my logic? Code is below:

```
var NSObject = ostypes.HELPER.class('NSObject');

if (!OSStuff.setWinAlwaysOnTop_class) {
    throw new Error('setWinAlwaysOnTop_class was not previously cleaned up!!')
}

var needsRegistration = true;
OSStuff.setWinAlwaysOnTop_class = ostypes.API('objc_allocateClassPair')(NSObject, 'setWinAlwaysOnTop_class', 0);
if (OSStuff.setWinAlwaysOnTop_class.isNull()) {
    console.info('setWinAlwaysOnTop_class:', class_NoitOnScrnSvrDelgt.toString());
    throw new Error('setWinAlwaysOnTop_class is null, so objc_allocateClassPair failed');
}

OSStuff.setWinAlwaysOnTop_jsMethods = {}; // holds key of aArrHwndPtrStr and value is js method

var IMP_for_mainThreadSelector = ctypes.FunctionType(ctypes.default_abi, ctypes.void_t, []);

OSStuff.setWinAlwaysOnTop_jsMethods[aArrHwndPtrStr[0]] = function() {
    console.log('setWinAlwaysOnTop_jsMethods ' + 0 + ' called');
};

OSStuff.setWinAlwaysOnTop_cMethods = {};
OSStuff.setWinAlwaysOnTop_cMethods[aArrHwndPtrStr[0]] = IMP_for_mainThreadSelector.ptr(OSStuff.setWinAlwaysOnTop_jsMethods[aArrHwndPtrStr[0]]);

OSStuff.setWinAlwaysOnTop_methodSelectors = {};
OSStuff.setWinAlwaysOnTop_methodSelectors[aArrHwndPtrStr[0]] = ostypes.API('sel_registerName')(aArrHwndPtrStr[0]);

var rez_class_addMethod = ostypes.API('class_addMethod')(OSStuff.setWinAlwaysOnTop_class, OSStuff.setWinAlwaysOnTop_methodSelectors[aArrHwndPtrStr[0]], OSStuff.setWinAlwaysOnTop_cMethods[aArrHwndPtrStr[0]], 'v');

if (needsRegistration) {
    ostypes.API('objc_registerClassPair')(OSStuff.setWinAlwaysOnTop_class);
    OSStuff.setWinAlwaysOnTop_allocation = ostypes.API('objc_msgSend')(OSStuff.setWinAlwaysOnTop_class, ostypes.HELPER.sel('alloc'));
    OSStuff.setWinAlwaysOnTop_instance = ostypes.API('objc_msgSend')(OSStuff.setWinAlwaysOnTop_allocation, ostypes.HELPER.sel('init'));
}

var rez_perform = ostypes.API('objc_msgSend')(OSStuff.setWinAlwaysOnTop_instance, ostypes.HELPER.sel('performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:'), ostypes.HELPER.sel(aArrHwndPtrStr[0]), ostypes.CONST.NIL, ostypes.CONST.YES);
console.error('perform done!!');
```